# Physical SSH access to Ubuntu 14.04 when network is unavailable?

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet

No DHCP assigned IP due Ubuntu seemingly auto-renaming ethernet device from `eth0` to `eth1`, despite only one ethernet device present.

Switching `/etc/network/interfaces` to use `eth1` may fix the problem but I've only got physical access to a non-sudo account unless I can somehow use an SSH key, perhaps via direct ethernet connection from my laptop.

Is that likely to work?

Are there any alteratives such as copying the key on USB or similar?

Comment: Why can't you login with the sudoer account using its password (the same one you type when using `sudo`)? Even if SSH logins are restricted to using key-based authentication, this does not apply to console logins. Worst case, boot in recovery mode.

Comment: Seconding that^, do you have physical access to the server, and can access the TTY logins, etc? Then login as the non-sudoer and SSH to localhost.

Comment: I have physical access. Also, I don't presently have the required SSH private key on the device but yeah I guess I can add that though I'm not familiar with using private keys from a linux account. Generally I login via putty from a windows machine. Thanks for helping me think through this!

Comment: Plot thickens. How do I mount a USB stick via console without root? :)